# Get a user to guess your lucky word with conditional operator

Tags: c#

For school I have the assignment to make a Console Program that lets the user guess my lucky word in this case "Lucky" and it needs to use a conditional Operator, now I can't seem to make it work in any way.

```
   namespace Assignment8
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ConsoleKeyInfo lucker = new ConsoleKeyInfo();
            string lucky = Console.ReadLine();
            return lucky == "Lucky" ? "That is Correct" : "That is Wrong!";
        }
    }
}
```

I hope u guys can atleast help me with this or give me some tips.

Comment: You can't return value from `void` method. Perhaps you want to print it instead.

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(lucky);` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to output the result to console, try:

```
Console.WriteLine(lucky == "Lucky" ? "That is Correct" : "That is Wrong!");
```

instead of returning value.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, this worked very well, I did edit it a little bit haha:
`Console.WriteLine(lucky == "lucky" ? $" {lucky} is Correct" : $" {lucky} is wrong!");`

Comment: No problem. Also I hope you understand why your original solution didn't work. Others pointed out the main problem with your code. So take a look at that and try too understan.

Comment: I do, and it's a pretty much beginners fault for not remembering about the return and void. But I'm glad stack overflow exists for such things hahaha:P

Answer (score 2):

I will give you only some hints/guidance, as you need to do this simple task yourself if you are at least one quarter serious about programming:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
       ^^^^
```

`Main` is a function which returns `void`. I.e. it doesn't return anything.

You don't want to return the message. Your main goal is to **print** the message to the console so that the user reads it. This is accomplished with `Console.WriteLine`.